# JW-player Not working in IE

Tags: php, jquery, jwplayer

I've the following problem, the following code:

```
$link = $_GET['link'];
$id = $_GET['block'];

echo "<p id='preview". $id ."'>The player will show in this paragraph</p>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";

echo "var s" . $id . " = new SWFObject('" . COMPANY_URL . "/system/addons/player/player.swf','player". $id ."','210','170','9');";
echo "s" . $id . ".addParam('allowfullscreen','true');";
echo "s" . $id . ".addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');";
echo "s" . $id . ".addParam('wmode','opaque');";

echo "s" . $id . ".addVariable('file', '" . $link  . "&repeat=always&autostart=true');";
echo "s" . $id . ".addVariable('skin', '" . COMPANY_URL . "/system/addons/player/simple-sources.swf');";

echo "s" . $id . ".write('preview". $id ."');";   
echo "</script>";
```

This is called every time by a jQuery load (this works because the  `echo "<p id='preview". $id ."'>The player will show in this paragraph</p>";` is showing).

In IE the player just leaves the 'player will show in this paragraph' while in all others browsers it is replaced by the jw-player. I can't find any solution on the forum of the jw-player or on stackoverflow...

Hope you guys can help!

**Updated**
The generated Source firebug

```
<p><div class="videofile" id="856">
<p id="preview856"><embed width="210" height="170" flashvars="file=http://DOMAIN/data/productinfo/pressbyopie/long-line/leesdeel-verdraait/1242649976__video_longline-verdraait.flv&amp;repeat=always&amp;autostart=true&amp;skin=http://DOMAIN/system/addons/player/simple-sources.swf" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" name="player856" id="player856" src="http://DOMAIN/system/addons/player/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></p>  </div></p>
```

Comment: The issue is unlikely be in the PHP. Can you post the code that is delivered to the browser (do a view source?). Also what version of IE are you using?

Comment: All IE from IE6 and higher. It's generated dynamicly so there is no souce. Edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the flv parsing I think.

when i added this:

```
echo "s" . $id . ".addParam('type','flv');";
```

It worked :)

Comment: That snippet comes after you ran `htmlspecialchars` on the `$id` right?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help solve your problem, but I feel compelled to point out that the PHP is a [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack waiting to happen:

```
$id = $_GET['block'];

echo "<p id='preview". $id ."'>The player will show in this paragraph</p>";
```

Try using `htmlspecialchars` with `ENT_QUOTES` on the `$id` before echoing it straight out into the HTML.

Even if this isn't production code, I don't like leaving such things posted on the interwebs for others to copy & paste ;)

---

PS: Would have commented on your question instead of providing an "answer" but I don't have enough rep yet.